# How to migrate SugarCRM modules to SuiteCRM

Tags: export, sugarcrm

I'm currently using SugarCRM but would like to migrate the modules to SuiteCRM. When I tried to export the module and added it to the module loader; I'm not sure to gain access to it if it is in the studio or what. I can't access module builder in SugarCRM either. I'm getting an error message saying access denied. How is it possible to export the modules into SuiteCRM?

Comment: Are these hosted or on-premise setups?

Comment: on premise setup

Comment: Are you following the instructions in the documentation for this transfer process? Is there any documentation on the error "access denied" from SuiteCRM? Does SuiteCRM support this transfer of modules?